# jqplot - click on background and redirect to specified URL?

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am using jqplot to display some bar graphs (with each bar representing number of items under each category). Right now I am able to click on bars using `jqplotDataClick` to redirect to a page which has a list of all those items under that category.

However, is there a way to click on actual background and redirect to another page? I would like to redirect to another page with large set of categories when I click on background. Before I made entire graph a link, but this removed the ability to click on individual bars (to get redirected to unique list page).

Here is code to click on bar (I want something similar, but for clicking on background):

```
$('#chart2').bind('jqplotDataClick', 
   function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
        window.location.href=data[2]
   }
);
```

I just want to know if there an event in jqplot for clicking on blackground or not.

Comment: Add code if you want to get any answer.

Comment: I just need to know if there is an event for clicking on background or not. Everything else for me is working.

Comment: as I said, nobody knows until you post some code.